# RelativeLayout background stretches when inner view aligned to parent right

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

The following XML results in the below image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/convoLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/right_bubble">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/convoBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"     // cause
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="test test test test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: stretched]

Is anyone aware of how to get it to look like this:

[image: fixed]

Note: I need the RelativeLayout as this is a dumbed down version of my XML :).

**EDIT:**

Let me also clarify. Without **android:layout_alignParentRight="true"** in the TextView, the layout looks like the image below (there is white padding on the right)

[image: no parent right]

In essence, I need that padding on the left.

**EDIT2:**

To further clarify, **@drawable/right_bubble** is a 9-patch image that is meant to stretch to house the inner views dynamically and the RelativeLayout is to have 3 TextViews inside of it, in which the 9-patch image should encapsulate all 3.

**EDIT3:**

This is what I want the end result to look like

[image: final]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are setting the background to relative layout... so, whole layout will have same background no matter what views it holds. Try setting "android:background="@drawable/right_bubble" to TextView instead.

**EDIT (by OP after getting answer from comments):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/convoLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"            // added
    android:background="@drawable/right_bubble" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/convoBody"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  // removed layout_alignParentRight
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="test test test test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As my note said, I need it to be in the RelativeLayout as there are other views I need in the chat bubble. If I only set the background for the TextView then the rest of the views won't be in the bubble.

Comment: OK, have you considered using frame layout inside Relative Layout to hold your views? you can set  android:layout_alignParentRight="true" to frame layout then..

Comment: Can you clarify on how I can use a FrameLayout to solve this problem? Let me also mention that @drawable/right_bubble is a 9-patch image that is meant to stretch to house the inner views dynamically.

Comment: can you tell me exactly how you want your screen to look like? including the other views that you need in chat bubble...

Comment: See EDIT3 SMS is a TextView and the time is a TextView. All 3 textviews are inside the RelativeLayout who's background is the 9-patch image of the blue bubble

Comment: That should be easy... have you tried setting layout_gravity of your RelativeLayout to 'right'?? It worked for me...

Comment: That worked. I may have been over complicating things by trying to set the inner TextViews alignParentRight="true". It only works when I do not do this. Thank you!

Comment: I have issues now. For some reason when running the application, the layout_gravity field for RelativeLayout is ignored (although it shows correct in Graphical Layout)

Answer (score 0):

J.Ajendra's answer got me most of the way there. His answer (that I edited in after understanding his comments) worked, but only if the RelativeLayout's container honors android:layout_gravity.  (for example, if we were to Activity#setContentView(R.layout.convo_item)).

In my case, convo_item.xml was to be inflated into a ListView which overrides this behavior for RelativeLayouts (I'm not sure why, but it does) resulting in the chat bubble always being on the left. To solve this, I simply wrapped the RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout that took the parents entire width (android:layout_width="match_parent") and set the gravity of it's content to "right" (android:gravity="right"). The result, it works for all cases including ListViews and Activity#setContentView(...).

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/convoOuterLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/convoLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/right_bubble" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/convoBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="test test test test"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```